# How to show message if datalist is not matching with the input tex?

Tags: html, html-datalist

how can I show message "Data is not available" if the input text is not matching with the datalist?

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
 <option value="Internet Explorer">
 <option value="Firefox">
 <option value="Chrome">
 <option value="Opera">
 <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```

Comment: no its not duplicate, i want to show message, if input text not matching.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox autocomplete clears if not match in option value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926516/textbox-autocomplete-clears-if-not-match-in-option-value)

Answer (score 2):

`<!---try this ;--->`

```js
    function CheckListed( txtSearch  ) {
     var objList = document.getElementById("browsers")  ;
     for (var i = 0; i < objList.options.length; i++) {
      if ( objList.options[i].value.trim().toUpperCase() == txtSearch.trim().toUpperCase() ) {
         return true }
      }
        alert( 'does not matched.') ;
        return false ; // text does not matched ;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="browsers" name="browser" onblur="CheckListed(this.value);">
    <datalist id="browsers">
     <option value="Internet Explorer">
     <option value="Firefox">
     <option value="Chrome">
     <option value="Opera">
     <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
```